# Replace date by text in date_popup default value (or in-field label)

Tags: datetime

I am desperately trying to display a date_popup field in my form with a text eg("please select date") as default value and not a date. Can someone help? 
Thanks a lot.
[image: my form now with date_popup]

[image: my code for the date_popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the placeholder html5 attribute by removing the #default_value from the array.

So, take out....

```
'#default_value' => $date,
```

and replace with

```
'#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Please select date')),
```

or, as you already have attribute, add it to that

Comment: Hi, thank you very much indeed for taking the time to reply. I have tried both solution but none seems to work unfortunately... any other idea? Thank you very much again

Comment: Sorry finally it works ! Brilliant thank you so much for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: That's great! Please mark my answer as correct if it helped!